# Internet in the router but not in the local network

Tags: windows-7, router

I have a PC and a laptop (Windows 7 - both) which should connect through router to Internet. The router is Linksys wrt120. My ISP is using PPPoE.

I have connected the Internet cable to the router, clone the MAC of my PC, writing the username and the password for my Internet connection. After seconds the router has acquired IP from my ISP. I have used the administration panel of Linksys and with the help of the ping and tracert commands which are built into it - I can connect to the world, outside the network.

The problem is when I try to connect the PC or the laptop to the network. There's no problem here. The DHCP server of the router gives them appropriate addresses. The problem is that they couldn't connect to either Internet addresses (google.com) or IP addresses. But they can connect to the router and its control panel.

I tried several times, reset the router..but there's no Internet..still.

One more thing: Windows 7 says after a diagnostic: "Your computer appear to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding."

Comment: Thank you to all but I find the solution (and the problem). My ISP has set the TTL to 1...so I have to change the router :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to all but I find the solution (and the problem). My ISP has set the TTL to 1...so I have to change the router :)

Comment: Looks like a case for TTL target in iptables...

Answer (score 2):

You might not have to clone your MAC at all if I remember correctly. But it has been a long time since I needed to use PPPoE.

Try to configure with out cloning the MAC and see what happens. Also verify that you are not using some sort of MAC filtering on your router. If you are be sure to add the needed MAC addresses of your local systems.

Comment: It is needed (the change of the MAC) because my ISP is filtering by it :)

Comment: Sounds like a fun ISP to deal with.

Comment: MAC filtering, modified TTL...I'm wondering what will follow :D

Comment: Most likely port "blocking" (stupid Charter and their port 80 shenanigans ......) it's my next most favorite thing.

Answer (score 1):

If [dns-troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/143479/internet-in-the-router-but-not-in-the-local-network/143501#143501) wont solve it, try and reset your router to default(factory) settings and start over with a clean plate.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a DNS related problem, as the error message suggests, it's worth checking to see if you have any connectivity at all.

Open a command prompt and type:

ping www.google.com

See if you get any replies. if not try:

ping 74.125.232.20

Again, see if you get a reply.

If the former fails and the latter works, it means you're not correctly configured to resolve DNS addresses. This is probably a configuration in the router.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me last night. Turns out there was a problem with my ISP and the modem wasn't getting any connection to the internet (though I did have connection to the router).

It resolved itself after about half an hour. As Pulse stated, make sure you check if you can even connect to the internet at all. It may be an ISP problem, or it may be DNS issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check If both the PC and laptop are set to automatically obtain the DNS server.

For more things to check, see [10 Ways to Troubleshoot DNS Resolution Issues](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/10-Ways-Troubleshoot-DNS-Resolution-Issues.html).